# Rails access array in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array in my model but i have to access in my view.When I am trying to access in my view I am getting undefined method 'each'. I am iterating using for each loop.
[document.rb]

```
@file_extension=[]
        files.each do |file|
            @file_extension=file.content_type.split('/')[1]         

            doc = Document.new(document: file,post_id: post_id )
            #save is a method which will save the content in the database 
            doc.save!
end
```

[documents/index.html.erb]

```
<% @file_extension.each do |f| %>
        <%= puts "ssssss#{f}"   %>
        <%end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reassigning the `@file_extension` variable, you should populate it:

```
@file_extension << file.content_type.split('/')[1]
```